# Acer Aspire 5532 Problem

Tags: power-management, acer-aspire

I have an [Acer Aspire 5532](http://us.acer.com/acer/product.do;jsessionid=C44477C9B495F244DCBB9D373A542992.public_a_us003?LanguageISOCtxParam=en&rcond5e.c2att92=145&inu49e.current.c2att92=145&link=ln314e&CountryISOCtxParam=US&kcond47e.c2att92=145&rcond159e.att21k=1&kcond48e.c2att101=68414&rcond190e.att21k=1&acond23=EU&rcond4e.att21k=1&sp=page17e&rcond157e.c2att92=145&var9e=793&ctx1g.c2att92=145&rcond42e.att21k=1&kcond50e.c2att92=145&rcond45e.att21k=1&rcond158e.c2att1=0&ctx2.c2att1=0&inu53e.current.c2att92=145&rcond38e.c2att1=0&var13e=EU&rcond44e.c2att1=0&rcond186e.c2att92=145&rcond3e.c2att1=0&rcond28e.attN2B2F2EEF=3206&rcond189e.c2att1=0&ctx1.att21k=1&CRC=1499151876) and am having a problem with turning it on. If you hit the power button to turn it on, it will light up and go to a black screen, no Acer logo or anything. You have to then hold the power button to turn it off, then turn it on again and it will turn on and load into Windows like normal. It has Windows 7 Home Premium, everything is stock from Acer.

Any idea what would cause this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happened to me too once or twice.. I think it may have to do with the battery memory. What I did was keep windows on without power saving anything, and let the battery completely die.. take out the battery and smack the power button a few times. put the battery back in, with the power plugged in, and let it charge completely.  No problems yet..

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem when I tried to shut down by closing the lid.  Either wouldn't go in to sleep mode at all or when you started up from sleep it locked up.  Geek Squad guy says there is a compatibility problem with Windows7.  He went in to power mode and set up for me to just tap the power button for sleep mode, then shut the lid.  Works fine!

Answer (score 1):

Do not do any of the above, your best option is to leave the computer plugged in and on or you will truly regret putting this computer into the sleep mode. It took me 3 hours to get my computer running again after trying the aforementioned.